# Set HotSpot properties on Android API 26 and above

Tags: android, hotspot, ssid

Since API 26 there is new way to turn on/off HotSpot, [startLocalOnlyHotspot](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#startLocalOnlyHotspot(android.net.wifi.WifiManager.LocalOnlyHotspotCallback,%20android.os.Handler))

But I can't set SSID and security keys anymore. The other problem is "startLocalOnlyHotspot" changes SSID and preSharedKey on each call, so it is almost impossible for user to set new SSID and key on other device every time.

I noticed when HotSpot is enabled programmatically, if user opens HotSpot activity, HotSpot will turn off after few seconds and If user re-enables HotSpot from HotSpot Wifi setup activity, it will use old configuration (old configuration before I update device to Android 8, same configuration I try to set programmatically).

Answer (score -1):

Create `WifiConfiguration` objet and set all related properties.

```
WifiConfiguration wifiCon = new WifiConfiguration();
wifiCon.SSID = "ssip";
wifiCon.preSharedKey = "Sharedpassword";
wifiCon.allowedAuthAlgorithms.set(WifiConfiguration.AuthAlgorithm.SHARED);
wifiCon.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.RSN);
wifiCon.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.WPA);
wifiCon.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.WPA_PSK);
try
{
    Method setWifiApMethod = wm.getClass().getMethod("setWifiApEnabled", WifiConfiguration.class, boolean.class);
    boolean apstatus=(Boolean) setWifiApMethod.invoke(wm, wifiCon,true);
} 
catch (Exception e) 
{
    Log.e(this.getClass().toString(), "", e);
}
```

Happy coding!!

Comment: Did you test your answer on Android 8, or just copy/pasted it from your old project?

Comment: You have to check with your build version, on my project is working fine with api level 25.

Comment: I did not ask about API 25.

Comment: check comments above "setWifiApEnabled" 
https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/wifi/java/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.java